# Create a vue-like plain component

Tags: javascript, components, ecmascript-5

Entry level. ES5 standard.

I have built a module:

```
import Person from './Person.js';

function Employer() 
{    
    Person.call(this);

    this.randomMethod = function() {
        console.log('randomMethod');
    }

    this.render = function(elem) {
        elem.innerHTML = this.compileTemplate();
    }

    this.compileTemplate = function() {
        return "<p onclick='this.randomMethod()'>Employer block</p>";
    }
}

export default Employer;
```

As you can see, it has its own view. So, now I am able to create as many objects as I want and bind them to DOM elements. As a next step I would like to teach them to execute its own methods (`randomMethod` in this case) without any global variables. To have a component, which knows how to render itself and how to process its events on es5 without any frameworks.

At least I need to emit a `CustomEvent` and I wouldn't like to have such long in-line code but a plain method call.

Something similar to Vue components, which have `template` and `methods` properties and you can call those methods from template.

Any ideas in this direction?

Comment: have you seen [Custom Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) ? It works everywhere reasonable these days. Also, you don't need to call `this.randomMethod`, just `randomMethod` works because inline event handlers are invoked as though you called them as `let event=arguments[0]; with(this){eval(attrCode)}`. you can also shorten `this.render = function(elem){` to `render (elem) {` if you put it in a class instead of a function.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: randomMethod is not defined`

Comment: in that case `this.randomMethod()` works as expected?

Comment: the same error. the only way to call the component's method is to get a pointer via a global variable (window object) and call it.

Comment: in my case pointer `this` within `onclick` event points on `<p>` html object